# Make up a reasonable definition for the bipartite complement of a bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am shooting from the hip here and seeing what sticks.

I tried this definition below which I am not sure works. If it doesn't, please, suggest more accurate definitions.

The reason I need this is that I want to be able to replace the degrees in $(4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2)$ (which is a degree sequence of a bipartite graph)  with smaller numbers.

---

Let $V$ be the set of vertices of a bipartite graph $G.$ Then $V$ is a union of two partite sets $X, Y$  and $\sum_{v_i \in X}deg(v_i) = \sum_{u_j \in Y}deg(u_j) = m.$

We can define graph $H = (A \cup B, F) = (\text {union of vertices, edges})$ to be bipartite complement of $G$ if $\sum_{d_i \in A}deg(d_i) = \sum_{e_j \in B}deg(e_j) = m.$

For example, suppose a bipartite(?) graph $T$ has partite sets of vertices represented by their degrees as $\{3, 4\}, \{2, 5\}.$ Then $T$'s bipartite complement has partite set of vertices represented by their degrees as $\{1, 6\}, \{1, 2, 4\}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written really doesn't make sense on a few levels. First of all, your definition of a bipartite complement of a graph is literally just another bipartite graph with the same number of edges. Additionally, in the example in the last paragraph that you give, I don't see have $\{3, 4\}$, $\{2, 5\}$ can be construed to be the degrees of all the vertices of a graph, no less a bipartite one (there aren't even five vertices, so how can a vertex have degree 5?). Also, with your first example, I don't exactly know what you mean by "able to replace the degrees in $(4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2)$...with smaller numbers".

Let me tell you what the ordinary definition of the bipartite complement of a bipartite graph is, and you can hopefully tell if this fits your needs. Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with parts $X$ and $Y$. Let $K(X, Y)$ be the complete bipartite graph with parts $X$ and $Y$. We define the bipartite complement of $G$ as $K(X, Y) - G$. That is, the bipartite complement of $G$ is the graph that has the same two parts as $G$ and has an edge between two vertices of different parts if and only if $G$ does not have an edge between those two vertices. This definition easily generalizes to $k$-partite graphs.

For example, let $G = C_6$, which is a bipartite graph as drawn below (with parts $X$ and $Y$). Then the bipartite complement of $G$, which I'll denote by $\overline{G}$, is composed of three disjoint edges:

[image: Graph and it's Bipartite Complement]

Comment: Consider the problem " Find a bipartite graph having the degree sequence $(4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2)$". Now "use the idea of the bipartite complement of a graph to solve the given problem   by replacing the degrees with smaller numbers." What can be done here?

Comment: @user463045 Now that is very much a different problem than what you've mentioned (you didn't mention why or how you wanted to replace the degree sequence with smaller numbers). I now see what you were trying to get across in your faux definition of a bipartite complement. This question is about the definition of bipartite complement, and that is what my answer addresses. If you would like help on realizing that bipartite degree sequence (the question you mention in your comment), I suggest you create another question. The new question can then be linked to and from this one.

Comment: @ Bob Krueger, one last question. Can you give an example of $K(X, Y) - G$ with particular $X, Y?$ Thanks.

Comment: @user463045 I've added an example.