# Find a bipartite graph realizing the degree sequence $\{4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2\}$. Use the bipartite complement to make the degrees smaller.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Easy way to do it (without the definition of bipartite complement):

We need two partite sets $X, Y$ such that the sum of degrees in $X$ and the sum of degrees in $Y$ are equal. If we represent the vertices in $X, Y$ by their degrees, we have $X = \{4, 3, 3, 3\}, \ Y = \{3, 3, 3, 2, 2\}$. This means this bipartite graph has $13$ edges. We now have enough info to try and draw a graph with the given specs. At this point, it's a little trial-and-error.

---

I tried and failed to find the right definition of bipartite complement so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that you can prove that the only way to bipartition the degree sequence in the hopes of realizing a bipartition graph with that sequence is in the way that you have stated, with the degrees of the vertices in $X$ being $\{4, 3, 3, 3\}$ and the degrees of the vertices in $Y$ being $\{3, 3, 3, 2, 2\}$ (prove this if you haven't already).

Next let's try to create a bipartite graph $G$ with parts $X$ and $Y$ that have vertices with degrees correspondingly listed above. Since these degrees are rather large compared to the number of vertices in each of the parts ($|X| = 4$, $|Y| = 5$), it will be easier to take the hint to look at the bipartite complement of $G$, which I will denote by $\overline{G}$. (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2356584/228620) for a definition of the bipartite complement I'm talking about.) If $v \in X$ has degree $d$ in $G$, then $v$ will have degree $5-d$ in $\overline{G}$. Similarly, if $v \in Y$ has degree $d$, then $v$ will have degree $4-d$ in $\overline{G}$. This means that the degree sequences of the two parts in $\overline{G}$ are $\{1, 2, 2, 2\}$ and $\{1, 1, 1, 2, 2\}$, respectively. Playing around with this a little, these degree sequences are realizable as a bipartite graph (prove this explicitly), so $\overline{G}$ can be realized. Then $G$ can be realized as the bipartite complement of $\overline{G}$, as desired.

Might I also say that we can't use the bipartite complement idea at the beginning, before we know what the partition should look like. The degree sequence of the bipartite complement depends on what bipartition we choose.

Comment: @ Bob Krueger, thanks. I see how this is done now.